# Google Picker API: Use of setAppId

Tags: google-drive-api, google-picker

Google picker api [examples](https://developers.google.com/picker/docs/index) has an file-open example which doesn't set the app id (setAppId) and an upload example which does it.

I would like to get clarifications:

- when do you need to set the api id?
- Can I have a web application downloading a file from Google drive using the file picker without an app id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the Google Drive SDK, always set the App ID.

https://developers.google.com/drive/integrate-open